# Common localization bugs with Hebrew

Tags: manual-testing, quality-assessment

I am looking into testing a translation of a website into Hebrew.

Would there be any common bug/issues that may occur on this language that I should keep an eye out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hebrew is right-aligned and can cause trouble especially when mixed with left-aligned languages. There are a few tips [here](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/web/tips/align.html).